# Python: List comprehension into an x,y list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am working with two ranges to place tiles in a 2d game, so I've created a 'tilemap'...

```
tilemap = [ [TILE for w in range(MAPWIDTH)] for h in range(MAPWIDTH)]
```

this works... now I want to attach instances of a class called 'piecemap' that corresponds to the tilemap. To do this I have a class called Piece that looks like this...

```
class Piece():
   otherstuff = "string"
   location = [0,0]
```

My question is how can I load the "w" in width range and the "h" in height range into the "location" attribute using list comprehension? Currently my effort (that doesn't work) looks like this...

```
piecemap = [[Piece.location[0] for w in range(MAPWIDTH)],[Piece.location[1] for h in range(MAPHEIGHT)]
```

I know it's wrong but no idea how to make it right! any help?

Comment: Exactly what are you expecting as output?

Answer (score 5):

```
class Piece():
   otherstuff = "string"
   location = [0,0]
```

That is a very odd-looking class. You have class attributes `otherstuff` and `location`, as if every `Piece` ever created would occupy the same location.

Rather, you probably want instance attributes, like so:

```
class Piece:
    def __init__(self, x, y, name="Unspecified"):
        self.location = [x,y]
        self.otherstuff = name
```

Then your list comprehension looks like:

```
tilemap = [ [Piece(w, h) for w in range(MAPWIDTH)] for h in range(MAPWIDTH)]
```

Comment: Of course, naming your indexes `h` and `w` in one place, but `x` and `y` in another might lead you to get your index order reversed, as I appear to have done here.

Answer (score 2):

From what I read, I assume the location is an attribute of each Piece `instance` (not a class attribute). The same goes for the `name` attribute (maybe).
Therefore, I would set the location when creating such objects:

```
class Piece():
    otherstuff = "string"
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.location = [x, y]
        # self.otherstuff = name # add it to the parameters if that's the case

piecemap = [[Piece(w,h) for h in range(MAPWIDTH)] for w in range(MAPHEIGHT)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for what you need Piece class, but you can retrieve all locations using `zip` function:

```
piecemap = zip(range(MAPWIDTH), range(MAPHEIGHT))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
>>> [[x,y] for x in range(3) for y in range(2)]
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 1]]
```

In your case it probably:

```
piecemap = [[Piece.location[0], Piece.location[1]] for w in range(MAPWIDTH)] for h in range(MAPHEIGHT)]
```

But I'm not sure what you're really expecting

Answer (score 1):

Don't you want something like this:

`tilemap = [ (w, h) for w in range(MAPWIDTH) for h in range(MAPWIDTH)]`

`MAPWIDTH = 3`

> > [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)

Then you can create your "Piece" objects?